# dockerrizing flask with mariadb

Tags: docker, flask, mariadb

Its my first time that i working with mysql and cant connect to container.
I trying to connect my flask application to mariadb into docker container
this is my dockerfile that contains this

```
volumes:
  db_data:

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/flask/Dockerfile
    image: flask
    command: /start
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    env_file:
      - .env/.dev
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.10
    restart: always
    hostname: db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: flask_celery"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE: flask_celery"
      - "MYSQL_USER: flask_celery"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD: flask_celery"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

In my env file thats in .env/.dev dir i have this

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql+pymysql://flask_celery:flask_celery@db/flask_celery
```

in entryproint my code looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

# If any of the commands in your code fails for any reason, the entire script fails
set -o errexit
# Fail exit if one of your pipe command fails
set -o pipefail
# Exits if any of your variables is not set
set -o nounset

mariadb_ready() {
python << END
import sys

import pymysql
import urllib.parse as urlparse
import os

url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])
print(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])
dbname = url.path[1:]
user = url.username
password = url.password
host = url.hostname
port = url.port

try:
    pymysql.connect(
        db=dbname,
        user=user,
        passwd=password,
        host=host,
        port=port
    )
except pymysql.OperationalError:
    sys.exit(-1)
sys.exit(0)

END
}
until mariadb_ready; do
  >&2 echo 'Waiting for MariaDB to become available...'
  sleep 1
done
>&2 echo 'MariaDB is available'

exec "$@"
```

But still dont have any connection to my db container

```
flask-web-1            | Waiting for MariaDB to become available...
flask-db-1             | 2023-08-01 20:01:01 1613 [Warning] Access denied for user 'flask_celery'@'172.20.0.8' (using password: YES)
```

Any one can help with it

Comment: The environment section of your `mariadb` container is invalid; running `docker-compose up` results in the error `You need to specify one of MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD, MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD_HASH, MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD and MARIADB_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD`. Compare the syntax in the `mariadb` container with your `web` container.